# GRE subject:volume created by revolving area about line

Tags: calculus, integration, solid-of-revolution

find volume created by revolving the region between $x=y^2$ and $y=x^2$ about the line $x=-1$.

My attempt is since to solve for $x$ first correct? so we have $x=y^2, x = \sqrt{y}$ so we. integrate from $0$ to $1$? I know its top function minus bottom but I forget do we do this

$$\pi \int_0^1 (y+1)^2 - \sqrt{y+1} dy$$

or is it this one? forget where to subtract the line really.

$$\pi \int_0^1 y^2 +1 - \sqrt{y} +1dy$$

thanks in advance I am studying for GRE subject, learned calc II in 2008 forgot most of it sadly. Hopefully the top integral is the correct set up but not sure.

Comment: thanks! was looking for that keyword cylindrical shells! still a bit stuck however

Comment: yeah I know that man lol I meant which of the two integrals

Comment: also I know how to foil man, im not asking how to foil I am asking you if my integral is set up correctly but you don't seem to want to answer that lol

Comment: well, it is just that it is a policy that we should not solve completely problems that may be homework problems. I believe you that it is a GRE question. I am just following the guidelines. I can check more carefully if you want. Give me a moment.

Comment: thanks :) yes just wanna know if setup of first integral is correct I am fully aware of the rules I didn't ask for an answer lol I myself have a discord server where I provide free math help as well I am against spoon feeding lol, thanks again so much for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would help to draw the region first. I am not sure how to do it here. But anyway, the formula the OP is looking for is the washer method formula (which I had incorrectly called the cylindrical shell method, thank you @MathLover for pointing it out), which gives in this case

$$ \pi \int_0^1 \left( (\sqrt{y} + 1)^2 - (y^2 + 1)^2 \right) dy. $$

Comment: ahhhh I forgot to square them!!!!!!! thank you a million! that's all I was missing

Comment: No worries. And sorry for the previous misunderstanding of your question.

Comment: its totally ok :) again thanks so much! this GRE subject is pulling from ALL areas of math lol many of which I merely forgot its been so long

Comment: Yes I know. I took it many years ago. Good luck!

Comment: lol thank you :)

Comment: What you are using is washer method and not cylindrical shell.

Comment: Aaah, thank you @MathLover. I will edit.